# Keycloak login and register actions not https

Tags: https, authentication, registration, keycloak

I have nginx that will handle https, but the login and register forms of keycloak have http actions and I can't find a way to set them to https.

Making them to https in the browser works correctly.

There are two variables:

```
{url.registrationUrl}
{url.loginAction}
```

Where are these values coming from?

EDIT:

I made a workaround

```
{url.registrationUrl?replace('http', 'https')}
```

Comment: have you tried setting enable ssl option? Option is present in realm-settings

Comment: yes, but then I need to configure an ssl certificate for the keycloak server, which I already did for nginx, it just seems a bit awkward. I keycloak was running on different machine inside a private network things could have been way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy-address-forwarding.

1. Forward the original schema in Nginx (server.conf)
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
2. Use this information in Keyclok (standalone/domain.xml)
   proxy-address-forwarding=true in http-listener

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#identifying-client-ip-addresses